# Update displayName of user in XMPP

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I am developing an iPhone app using robbiehanson/XMPPFramework & Openfire. On my app coredata roster table each user has an entry called "displayName". I am using this display name for friends listing.

My question is: How can I edit this "displayName" of my user account to reflect these changes on my friends roster table? I tried to do it by updating my vCard, but the display name is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display name is likely the name attribute in the roster.

Reference: [RFC 6121](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-2.1.2.4)

Comment: Display name is the property related to a user..is it ? so then why it can't be changed by updating the vCard of the same user ?

Comment: No name in roster is set by roster owner. From RFC: "The 'name' attribute of the <item/> element specifies the "handle" to be associated with the JID, as determined by the user (not the contact). "

Comment: So the displayName is associated with the user roster....so it can be updated only by updating the roster...right ?

Comment: @AbhijithG Hi I am also need to change the user Display Name. Please help me